# How to make an Excel Function to assign users to a group?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I created a form contact with Google Forms and linked the form to a Google Sheets file. Each time a person fills the form, the Google sheets is actualized with the answers. I want to automatically assign each user to a group based on their responses. A group would be formed by a set of criteria. Example :
If user_1 answered : sex=woman, age=30, color=blue then she would be assigned to group 1
If user_2 answered : sex=man, age=50, color=green then he would be assigned to group 2
An user could be assigned to multiple groups if it fills the group criteria

What function could I use ?

[The file would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVnFh.png)

I tried to use IF functions but I think that I don't know enough to make it work

Answer (score 0):

First, start by creating a criteria for each group.

For example, Group 1: Age needs to be between 20 and 25. Eye Color is green OR blue, and so on.

Then, run multiple IF statements nested with AND functions to assign a group.

Let's assume User 1 is a male, 30 years old, and eye color is brown.

IF(AND(User_1_sex='MALE',OR(User_1_eye_color = 'BLUE', User_1_eye_color = 'GREEN'), User_1_age >= 20, User_1_age <= 30),'Group1',another IF statement)